# Invertibility under base change for the Weyl algebra instead of for the polynomial algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, automorphisms, weyl-algebra, jacobian-conjecture

From [Lemma 1.1.8](https://books.google.co.il/books?redir_esc=y&id=wKJqqd8t8KUC&q=base%20change#v=snippet&q=base%20change&f=false), we obtain the following:
Assume that $R \subseteq S$ are commutative rings
and
$u: R[x,y] \to R[x,y]$ is an $R$-algebra endomorphism
that has an invertible Jacobian, namely,
$Jac(u(x),u(y)) \in R^*$.
Denote $A:=u(x) \in R[x,y]$, $B:=u(y) \in R[x,y]$
and let
$v: S[x,y] \to S[x,y]$ be the $S$-algebra endomorphism
defined as follows:
$v: (x,y) \mapsto (A,B)$
(and extended to $S[x,y]$ in the obvious way).
If $v$ is an automorphism of $S[x,y]$,
then $u$ is an automorphism of $R[x,y]$.

Denote the first Weyl algebra over $R$ by $A_1(R)$; by definition it is the $R$-algebra generated by $x$ and $y$ such that $yx-xy=1$.

> Is it possible to replace $R[x,y]$ and $S[x,y]$ by $A_1(R)$ and $A_1(S)$?

Namely, assume that $u: A_1(R) \to A_1(R)$, $u: (x,y) \mapsto (A,B)$, $[B,A]=1$,
and let $v: A_1(S) \to A_1(S)$, $v: (x,y) \mapsto (A,B)$. If $v$ is an automorphism of $A_1(S)$, then $u$ is an automorphism of $A_1(R)$.

**Remarks:** **(1)** One has to be careful, since perhaps $A_1(R)$ or $A_1(S)$ are not simple rings (I do not know for which commutative rings $T$, $A_1(T)$ are simple; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658511/for-which-commutative-rings-r-the-first-weyl-algebra-a-1r-is-simple)).
**(2)** Further assume that $R$ and $S$ are integral domains of characteristic zero. Probably a counterexample to my question is a counterexample to the Dixmier Conjecture, so (since I 'believe' in the Dixmier Conjecture) I guess there is no counterexample. But how to prove the claim?